# show different menu for users and admins

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have never tried this, but have been searching alot around to find the answer, but i cant seem to get things to work rly.

This i what i have:

Login script:

```
    $submitted_username = ''; 


    if(!empty($_POST)) 
    { 

        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                id, 
                name,
                username, 
                password, 
                salt, 
                email 
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                username = :username 
        "; 


        $query_params = array( 
            ':username' => $_POST['username'] 
        ); 

        try 
        { 

            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 

            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 


        $login_ok = false; 


        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
        if($row) 
        { 

            $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $row['salt']); 
            for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
            { 
                $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['salt']); 
            } 

            if($check_password === $row['password']) 
            { 

                $login_ok = true; 
            } 
        } 

        if($login_ok) 
        { 

            unset($row['salt']); 
            unset($row['password']); 


            $_SESSION['user'] = $row; 


            header("Location: home.php"); 
            die("Redirecting to: home.php"); 
        } 
        else 
        { 

            print("Feil med innlogging."); 


            $submitted_username = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
        } 
    } 

?>
```

Common.php:

```
$options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'); 


try 
{ 

    $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options); 
} 
catch(PDOException $ex) 
{ 

    die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
} 


$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 


$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 


if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
{ 
    function undo_magic_quotes_gpc(&$array) 
    { 
        foreach($array as &$value) 
        { 
            if(is_array($value)) 
            { 
                undo_magic_quotes_gpc($value); 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                $value = stripslashes($value); 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_POST); 
    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_GET); 
    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_COOKIE); 
} 


header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 


session_start();
```

Now i have 2 headers.
One header for normal users and one header for the site admin.

In my SQL i have id, name, username, password, salt, email and userLevel

I have set userlever for normal users to "user" and for site admin it is set as "admin".

Now i want the sites to show header.php for normal "user" and adminheader.php for "admin".

Can anyone explain how i can do that with what i have here?

Thanks.
(I know some code may be bad, but i'm still learning.)

Comment: Store the `userlevel` in a `SESSION`. Then use a conditional; if admin show admin menu, else show standard menu.

Comment: Okey. How do i set up this session?
Can i just do $_SESSION["userLevel"] = "admin" ; in another file or what?

Comment: Yes, start the session first. Do it in the login script. You'll also need to start the session on the page you are showing the menus on.

Comment: So at the bottom of my login script i can do:

session_start();
$_SESSION["userLevel"] = "admin";


before the login form?

All my pages after index.php contains common.php and at the bottom of common.php i have session_start();

Comment: Dont do `$_SESSION["userLevel"] = "admin";` that will set everyone as an admin do `$_SESSION["userLevel"] = $row['userlevel'];` or whatever the column and return are set as. Don't do it on the login form either, have it on the login processing script.

Comment: Then i get this error: 

Notice: Undefined variable: row in /storage/content/79/101379/micbra.mgdata.no/public_html/php/common.php on line 57

Then i put this in common.php:

session_start();
$_SESSION["userLevel"] = $row['userLevel'];

Comment: I said `or whatever the column and return are set as`. You cant just use a variable that isn't defined.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution you can try. You can include another php file into your file using `include`. For example `include myfile.php;`

After login you are saving user data in `SESSION`. Now check if the user is `admin` or `user` then include file accordingly.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user']['userLevel']) && $_SESSION['user']['userLevel'] == "admin")
    include 'adminheader.php';
else
    include 'header.php';
```

Comment: I take it that what you posted is pseudo code, correct? If it isn't, it's full of errors.

Comment: you missed the closing statements here and I had to fix that "for you".

Comment: oops my bad. Thanks

Comment: I am using sessions in my other files.. f.eks:<?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

Comment: But when i use if($_SESSION['user']['userLevel'] == "admin")
    include 'adminheader.php';
else
    include 'header.php';

Then i get: Undefined variable _SESSION

Comment: You have to add `session_start();` at the top of the files you want to work with `session`.

Comment: Session_start(); is at the bottom of common.php and common.php is included in all files.

If i add another session_start() i get a message saying that session is already started.

Comment: start session at top of the page not bottom. Remove the bottom one.

Comment: Okey. Now i did that.
Now i dont get any error's, but it makes everyone use header.php and it ignores adminheader.php

Comment: `adminheader.php` will be visible only to the users with `admin` userLevel

Comment: I am logged in with the user admin. I did store the session in common.php, but it seems like it's wrong. I think i have done something wrong in storing the session!

Comment: What does `echo $_SESSION['user']['userLevel'];` prints in `common.php`

Comment: Now when i go to my page: home.php where session is starting and i write the code from above to show different menu's i get this error: Notice: Undefined index: userLevel

Comment: If user is properly loged in and session is started properly there should not be this type of error. Try latest edited code.

Comment: One error from home.php went away, but not from common.php
I guess this is not the right way to store session? : $_SESSION['user']['userLevel'];

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: userLevel in /storage/content/79/101379/micbra.mgdata.no/public_html/php/common.php on line 58

Comment: Check if are loged in. Did update the code in common.php with latest edited code?

Comment: Logged out now, and now i notice even more problems.
When i now log in with my admin account, i get logged in with the user account. So now it looks like logout wont work.